# Verify if crontab works

Tags: cron

I want to verify if a certain crontab works properly. I have added a job like this:

```
  */2 * * * * /path_to_my_php_script/info.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I know that i redirect to the null device, but i not sure if the above command is good.

*Edit 1: In my /var/log/syslog every two minutes i have the following error:

```
 (CRON) error (grandchild #2788 failed with exit status 2)
```

*Edit 2: No errors in logs with this new job:

```
 */2 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path_to_my_php_script/info.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: unfortunately all above tried but does not work for me. as you say the trial /bin/sh -c "(export PATH=/bin; /tmp/trial.sh </dev/null)" shows below message, not sure what it is /bin/sh: PATH=/bin: is not an identifier

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The syntax for the crontab entry looks correct. Indeed, if you edit your crontab using "`crontab -e`" (as you should), you'll get an error if you specify a syntactically invalid crontab entry anyway.

1. Firstly, does `/path_to_my_php_script/info.php` run correctly from the command-line?
2. If so, does it also run correctly like this?:

   ```
   /bin/sh -c "(export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin; /path_to_my_php_script/info.php </dev/null)"
   ```
3. If that works, does it work like this?

   ```
   /bin/sh -c "(export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin; /path_to_my_php_script/info.php </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1)"
   ```

Step (3) is similar to how cron will run your program (as documented in "man 5 cron".

The most likely problem you're having is that the PATH cron is using to run your program is too restrictive. Therefore, you may wish to add something like the following to the top of your crontab entry (you'll need to add in whatever directories your script will need):

```
PATH=~/bin:/usr/bin/:/bin
```

Also note that cron will by default use `/bin/sh`, not bash. If you need bash, also add this to the start of your crontab file:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

Note that both those changes will affect **all** the crontab entries. If you just want to modify these values for your `info.php` program, you could do something like this:

```
*/2 * * * * /bin/bash -c ". ~/.bashrc; /path_to_my_php_script/info.php"
```

It's also worth mentioning that on a system configured for "mail" (in other words a system which has an MTA configured [sendmail/postfix/etc]), all output from crontab programs is sent to you via email automatically. A default Ubuntu desktop system won't have local mail configured, but if you're working on a server you can just type "mail" in a terminal to see all those cron mails. This also applies to the "`at`" command.

Comment: I get permission denied for 2nd step. What should i do?

Comment: @akikara chmod +x ./cron.sh - obviously replace ./cron.sh with whatever the location of your file is that you're trying to run

Answer (score 109):

Although very rare, sometimes cron stops working properly even though the service is running. Here is how to verify that crond is running and stop/start the service.

**Using systemctl:**

```
systemctl status cron
systemctl restart cron
```

**Older methods:**
On CentOS and other Red Hat-based systems:

```
service crond status
service crond stop
service crond start
```

On Ubuntu and other Debian-based systems:

```
service cron status
service cron stop
service cron start
```

Comment: Seems to be `/etc/init.d/cron status` on my machine.

Comment: @mpen `service` is for systemd (which was adopted by many Linux distributions). Older releases and some distributions may still be using the old System V  scripts in `/etc/init.d`.

Comment: This happened to me me into a docker machine.
I would check this before more complex solutions.

Comment: Works also in WSL2

Comment: `systemctl status cron`

Answer (score 37):

Do not redirect error output to /dev/null and grep /var/log/syslog for cron output.

```
grep cron /var/log/syslog
```

You can immediately show errors when saving a file after editing `/etc/crontab` or files inside `/etc/cron.d/` with:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep --line-buffered cron
```

If the edit is ok, you will only see the `RELOAD` notice, errors will occur like

```
Jul 9 09:39:01 vm cron[1129]: Error: bad day-of-month; while reading /etc/cron.d/new
```

Answer (score 23):

You can see your active cron with the terminal command:

```
crontab -l
```

Here are the parameters in order:

1. min (0 - 59)
2. hour (0 - 23)
3. day of month (1 - 31)
4. month (1 - 12)
5. day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0)
6. command

So, you are calling your script every first minute of each hour. You should test your output at a more often interval for testing purpose:

```
* * * * * <command> #Runs every minute
```

This will call it every minute!

Comment: */2 * * * * i have changed to every two minutes now

Answer (score 20):

Old question and many complicated answers. The easiest way is to add this line to your crontab

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'date > ~/cron-test.txt'
```

It will simply every minute write the current date to the file `~/cron-test.txt`

Then you just run `cat ~/cron-test.txt` and check if the shown date is the current date. If it is crontab is working correctly.

Answer (score 10):

For the time part on each line, you can use this [cron tester](http://cron.schlitt.info/) to test/verify your cron time definition.

Comment: also useful: http://www.crontab-generator.org/

Comment: broken link to cron tester

Comment: @Seamus the link is broken now but not when I had answered, so please don't down vote

Comment: If there were **anything** of any value at all here - other than a link to the answer, I wouldn't downvote. But without that link, your answer definitely is in the category of `This answer is not useful`. I'm sorry, but if you want to edit your answer, I'll gladly take another look. I don't like to downvote - this is only my 2nd downvote here in almost 4 years.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can also use `run-parts` to run cron jobs out of band. It is actually what cron uses itself to run the periodic cron jobs, so by supplying the appropriate arguments you can run them at any time.

If you just want to run one file instead of all the cron jobs defined in eg `/etc/cron.daily` you will have to supply the regex argument along with a valid regex. `run-parts --list --regex '^p.*d$' /etc`

Keep in mind that cron jobs are typically named without an extension and marked as executable, so make sure your scripts are similar, though using a regex may allow you to trigger a script with an extension.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have to check the **cronjob** status :

```
systemctl status cron
```

after that, run this command in the shell :

```
crontab -e
```

and add this line to **crontab**:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'date >> /tmp/cron-test.txt'
```

this command writes the **current date every minute** in the cron-test file, you can watch the crontab output with the following:

```
cat /tmp/cron-test.txt
```

you should have an **output** like this after 4 minutes :

```
Mon Mar  6 11:55:01 UTC 2023
Mon Mar  6 11:56:01 UTC 2023
Mon Mar  6 11:57:01 UTC 2023
Mon Mar  6 11:58:01 UTC 2023
```

now, if you can see this output your crontab **works well**, else you can see your log and find your issue's reason

```
grep cron /var/log/syslog
```

done.

Answer (score 1):

ah !!

got the answer myself, I checked and did not find `crond` inside the default installation directory i.e `/etc/init.d/`

will now try and reply.

note -- I did check the `cron.allow`, `cron.deny` too. All is fine so far.